# Pass a field to custom deserializer class Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have written a custom deserializer to map only the required fields using jackson. Here goes.

```
public class GeneralDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<GeneralDomain> {

    @Override
    public GeneralDomain deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        final JsonNode jsonNode = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        final Map<String, String> map = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(jsonNode, Map.class);
        final String event = "Proxy";
        return new GeneralDomain(map.get("id"), event, map.get("name"), map.get("lastLogin"));
    }

    @Override
    public Class<GeneralDomain> handledType() {
        return GeneralDomain.class;
    }
}
```

I have a mixin class too for this to add extra annotations.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = GeneralDeserializer.class)
public class GeneralDomainMixIn{}
```

I fetch the object in this way,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(GeneralDomain.class, SimpleRevealPublicEventMixIn.class);
String json = "{\"id\": 111, \"name\": David, \"lastLogin\": \"02-10-2016 10:32:00 AM\"}";
GeneralDomain readValue = mapper.readValue(json, GeneralDomain.class);
```

This works great. But as you can see in the custom deserializer, I am hard coding the event field value. This will be passed on by some other instance variable in the main class. I have to pass this field to the custom deserializer. So is there a way to access this variable inside the deserializer? Or is there any other alternative way to achieve this? Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133161/how-to-pass-constructors-parameters-with-jackson. Does this help?

Comment: @DanielScott sorry for the late reply. Yes I did go through the link that you posted. The problem for me is that I have a MixIn class which uses `@deserialize` annotation. Even If i create a constructor to take the value that I need to pass, how how to do this with MixIn class? Can you please explain if you know? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got the answer finally. Thanks to Philip in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879286/jackson-pass-values-to-jsondeserializer).

All I had to do was this.

Create an instance of InjectableValues

```
private InjectableValues injectEventType() {
  return new InjectableValues.Std()
    .addValue("event", "proxy")
}
```

use this method to set the `injectEventType` method in mapper class

```
GeneralDomain readValue = mapper.setInjectableValues(injectEventType()).readValue(json, GeneralDomain.class);
```

In my deserialize method I had to retrieve the values provided by the InjectableValues:

```
String event = String.valueOf(ctxt.findInjectableValue("event", null, null));
```

Comment: That helped. Note: I needed the `@JacksonInject(attributeName)` annotation for all the injected attributes in (here) `GeneralDomain.class`