# Store a variable in DeserializationContext with Jersey

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, json-deserialization

I have a custom JSON deserializer for MyClass, declared like:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=MyClassDeserializer.class)
public class MyClass {
...
```

and defined as

```
 public class MyClassDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public MyClass deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
    ...
```

Then, I use a Jersey Client object to call a Web service and convert the JSON into an instance of MyClass:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
Client httpClient = Client.create(clientConfig);

WebResource webResource = httpClient.resource("theUrl");
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").type("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
...

MyClass myClass = response.getEntity(MyClass.class);
```

My question is this: how do I to store a variable in the DeserializationContext?

I saw [Pass a field to custom deserializer class Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049957/pass-a-field-to-custom-deserializer-class-jackson), but I'm not explicitly creating a mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work by adding this in the deserialize method:

```
Long value = (Long) ctxt.findInjectableValue("abc", null, null);
```

And this before the call to create the Client:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setInjectableValues(newInjectableValues());
JacksonJaxbJsonProvider jacksonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
jacksonProvider.setMapper(mapper);
clientConfig.getSingletons().add(jacksonProvider);
```